# Can't override XML config settings:ConfigurationErrorsException: Invalid key value

Tags: c#, xml, config

I am trying to build a console application, where the user can decide, wether to enable logging or not. For that I got a app.config file in XML format. The Code can succesfully read the current state, but when I am trying to override the "protocol" property, I get the given exception in Line 27

My protocol class:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    
    namespace Bruch
    {
        class Protokoll
        {
            
            public Protokoll()
            {
                string protokollConfigStatus = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("protokoll");
    
                if (protokollConfigStatus == "unknown")
                {
                    SetzeEinstellung("protokoll", "test");
                };
            }
    
            public static void SetzeEinstellung(string key, string value)
            {
                Configuration configuration =
                    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                configuration.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;
****************configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);     //this line
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
            }
        }
    
    }
```

my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
       <add key="protokoll" value="unknown" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The error message:

```
>System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: "An error occurred executing the configuration >section handler for configProtectedData."
>
>inner exception:
>ConfigurationErrorsException: Invalid key value.
```

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: Sorry, it's line 27,
>configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);

Comment: Sidenote: I really recommend using english terminology when choosing method, class, field and other names. Makes it really much easier for international audiences.

Comment: My college teacher insists on german "speaking" names, I should have changed it, sorry

Comment: No problem. In this case, it's quite obvious :)

Comment: I am trying to look it up right now. But I _think_ ( if I remember correctly ) application settings cannot be set at runtime. User settings can. But I don't know if that's still true. Or if I remember correctly for that matter.

Comment: So I shouldn't save the property inside AppSettings, but in another container?

Comment: Yep, I remembered right: _"Settings that are application-scoped are read-only, and can only be changed at design time or by altering the .config file in between application sessions."_ - [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: ^^ The document that link takes you to also gives you the correct alternative to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Settings that are application-scoped are read-only, and can only be changed at design time or by altering the .config file in between application sessions.

Source: [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

So, what you need - if you so want to write settings at runtime - are *user* settings.